# Ada - access constant confusion

Tags: ada

Say I have a type:

```
type A;
type XA is access constant A;
type A is
   record
      Member : Natural :=  1;
      Neighbor : XA;
   end record;
```

I'm confused about the access constant part.
If I instantiate a instance of `XA` that points to a  instance of `A`, what can I change while only holding the reference to the `XA` "instance" ?

Can I change the member of the object that `XA` points to ? I'd say no, but what about the Neighbor of the `A` in the `XA` object ?

Can someone explain the use of `access constant` to me ?

Comment: Please note that you usually can manage quite fine in Ada without using access types.

Comment: @Jacob, true, but it’s hard to roll your own list without.

Comment: But when do you roll your own list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a small example showing what it does:

```ada
procedure Access_Constant is

   type XA is access constant Integer;

   A : aliased Integer;
   X : XA;
begin
   X := A'Access;
   X.all := 4;
end Access_Constant;
```

When you attempt to compile it, the assignment to `X` works fine (`X` is a variable), while the assignment to `X.all` is forbidden (as `X.all` is a constant - per the definition of `XA`).

Although `XA` is declared to point to a `constant Integer`, even a variable is acceptable, but you can only treat a dereference of an `XA` entity as a `constant Integer`, even if the object is a variable.

Comment: so just to get this straight, if a `access constant` appears on the left side, in any way, I cannot assignt it any value on the right side ?

Comment: No.  But you can't assign a value to a `constant`.  If you try to compile the example, you will see that `X := A'Access` works fine.

Comment: @zython I think it is more like `constant` applies to the right side. That is `access constant Integer;` should be read as "access to constant integer", not like "access constant to integer".

Comment: The other meaning is written `constant access`.